# the spinner selected value is not assigning the global variable

Tags: java, android

```
newBatsmanSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if (i>0)
                {
                    String text= newBatsmanSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    newBatsman=text;
                    //Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
```

i want when click on item it assign the value to global variable but it dont

Comment: what is the value that set as global ?

Comment: String newBatsman;

Comment: Perhaps your `i` is less than 0 ? Try print out value `i` ?